# Query for certain rows and order those by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array of **ids** that are unique in the context of the table for each row. What I would like to do is to query the database and obtain ordered by date of insertion (it is already a field in the table) but **only those tables which id is in the array**

`$query = SELECT this,andthis,andthis,andthis FROM table WHERE id=(inside array of ids)? ORDER BY date_of_insertion;`

The result is to be `fetch_assoc()` and therefore obtaining a associative array. What I would really want would be something like this in the final array:

> [1] id, this, andthis,andthis,andthis
>
> [2] id, this, andthis,andthis,andthis
>
> [3] ...

**even** if the table has other ids and rows that just **weren't queried** because they weren't in the specified array. Those that were queried should be ordered by time. Any ideas on how to achieve the best performance on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
// this is the array of ids
$array_of_ids = array();

// joins the ids in the array into a string, separating each id with a comma
$ids = implode(',', $array_of_ids); 

$query = "SELECT this, andthis, andthis, andthis FROM table WHERE id IN (" . $ids . ") ORDER BY date_of_insertion";
```

Comment: yeah, nicely thought! I'll try it and let you know if it worked out.